# Passing Dropdown Choice to Modal Using Django For Loop

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-5

I have a dropdown with choices. The dropdown should be linked to a modal where I'd like to say "You selected Choice A" (or B or C), depending on what was clicked.

I tried `data-target="#myModal{{choice}}"` and `id="myModal{{choice}}"`, hoping that they would be linked, but with this, the modal won't show up at all.

The modal appears when I remove `{{choice}}` though, but that's not what I want.

Thanks for reading. Your help would be much appreciated.

views.py:

```
def modal_home(request):
    choices = [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
    ]

    return render(request, 'modal/test-modal.html', {
        'choices': choices,
    })
```

test-modal.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Create
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                {% for choice in choices %}
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{choice}}">{{ choice }}</a>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{choice}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">MODAL</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                </button>
                </div>
                    <p>Here I want to say "You selected Choice A"</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>   

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to do another loop and create a `.modal` for each of  the  `choices`

Comment: @ArleighHix Yes, wrapping the modal div with another loop worked. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do another loop and create a `.modal` for each of the `choices`.

```
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Create
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
            {% for choice in choices %}
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{choice}}">{{ choice }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>

  {% for choice in choices %}

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{choice}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">MODAL</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            </button>
            </div>
                <p>You selected Choice {{ choice }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   

  {% endfor %}
```